# php: get variables visible in function

Tags: php, scope

is there any way to get list of variables that were defined in function, or list of all accessible variables in a function?

Comment: for what purpose? documentation?

Comment: get_defined_vars(); But it returns an array of all defined variables not specific to a function.

Comment: @Asif nope, it should work fine if called within the function

Comment: Yes, Later realized the same.

Comment: i just include files within a function and i need to make variables defined there global, this is not great decision, but there is no better solution for now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [`get_defined_vars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php):

> This function returns a multidimensional array containing a list of all defined variables, be them environment, server or user-defined variables, within the scope that get_defined_vars() is called.

it has to be called within each function you want to analyze, though.

Comment: thanks, im an idiot, just read the manual for that function before posting question, but couldnt test it normally because of mistake in code

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

Documentation indeed ^^

Answer (score 0):

func_num_args — Returns the number of arguments passed to the function
func_get_arg — Return an item from the argument list
func_get_args — Returns an array comprising a function's argument list

Comment: thanks, but i needed vars defined in the function, not that are passed to func